# How to set as startup project in visual studio 2017 using if any short cut key?

Tags: visual-studio, startup, visual-studio-2017

Is there any short-cut key to set a project as startup project in visual studio solution explorer?

Answer (score 12):

You can define your own shortcut for that action via Tools -> Options -> Environment/Keyboard.

Search for "Project.SetasStartUpProject" and assign whatever shortcut you want.

Answer (score 10):

Select the project, press `Shift + F10`, press `a`.

Comment: Many keyboards also have the `menu key` (the button between right `Windows key` and `Ctrl`), which can be pressed instead of `Shift + F10`.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the project and press <kbd>a</kbd>